# Carbon. Локаль одна, а дни недели с другого языка

Tags: laravel, locale, carbon

Carbon v2.39.0

Почему `locale` = `uk` а `localeDayOfWeek` = `Thursday` а не `Вівторок`.
Например метод объекта `diffForHumans` выдает правильный результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин имеющихся файлов с похожим именем чтобы не осталось сомнений что это `Ukrainian` а не `United Kingdom`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Lang/uk.php:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Lang/uk_UA.php:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/List/languages.php:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/2178
Мне помогли выяснить что я не правильно делал, нужно использовать ->dayName потому что ->localeDayOfWeek является устаревшим

Answer (score 4):

Потому что uk - это не Украина, а United Kingdom, то бишь Великобритания. А Украина - это ua.

Comment: Код файла `uk` содержит слова украинского языка. Код файла `uk_UA` содержит ссылку на файл `uk`